# Would querying 60 columns from a Snowflake table would cost me more than querying 20 columns?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, distributed-database, cost-management

We are trying to find a less expensive way and more manageable way have our queries being stored and executed.  One approach is to retrieve information from 60 columns every time someone queries and the other option is to make do with whatever columns necessary. Will there be a massive cost impact?

Scenario:
We have a view which reads and does some calculations using 60 columns and we perform select on let's say 5 metrics which would have been calculated using just 15 columns.

Another approach is, only selecting those 15 columns and providing result.

Would former approach cost more than latter one? What would be extent?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on multiple levels.

A couple of ways:

1. Processing power to parse all 60 columns values oppose by 20 columns.
2. Network IO: More columns imply more network IO for transferring data from cloud to client-side. So in this case it will take roughly 2 times more IO while using 60 columns. ( Of course, it depend upon column data type, size, etc )

Even though it doesn't seem much, every inefficient queries add to the cost bit by bit and will cost a lot especially if you are planning to use this for the long term.